# Which characters are double quoted in row constructor in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, double, quoting

When one creates a row constructor Postgres will enclose the value in double quotes if it contains certain characters

```
select row('test')::text  -> test
select row('test,')::text -> "test,"
select row('te(st')::text -> "te(st"
```

So far I have found that the following characters anywhere in text will make the text the double quoted: space , ) ( " \

Is there a list of all characters producing double quoting?

Comment: Spaces will also force quoting.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to read the source, but I think you got them all. It is the list of characters that have a special meaning in the string representation of a value of type `record`.